# In flutter how to show bottom sheet only once

Tags: flutter, share

I use the library: https://pub.dev/packages/share

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Jxvk.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PppS.png)

And when pressing quickly and continuously on a button, many bottom sheets are displayed. How to only have 1 bottom sheet visible?

Comment: Add some code that you have done to achieve this.

Comment: i added it. image1 and image 2

Comment: Code _as text_. Read [ask] and [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Question: What you can do to avoid this?
Answer: Declare a bool right here =>

```
class YourAppState extends State<YourApp> {


bool _isClicked = false;
```

and then use it in your method _showShare()

```
void _showShare() async {
if(!_isCLicked)
{
   await Share.share("https://xxxx.com");
   _isCLicked =true;
}

}
```

and when you want to use that share feature again revert its value to false.

Comment: @NamNguy let me know if it doesn't work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag for your problem when ever user select sharing icon, your flag will be  false and when sharing modal will open completely your flag will be true again.
finally use your flag for handling that is user selecting the sharing icon or not